# Jenkins does not update build result to better result

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I have a groovy script that changes the build result using setResult(hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS).

But I realized that I cannot change the job result to a better result (only to worse ones). If I will change the code to: build.setResult(hudson.model.Result.Unstable), then when the build will be successful the result will be changed (I can see in the Console Output: Build step 'Groovy Postbuild' changed build result to UNSTABLE.)
But I can't update the result to a better one.

Is there any solution?
(The same problem occurs with groovy postbuild) .

EDIT:
I'm using the MultiJob plugin in my main job for running 3 downstream jobs (named job1, job2, job3). And I wrote a groovy script so that the result of the main job will be determine only by the first two downstream jobs (when job1 and job2 are success, and job3 is unstable - I wish to set the main job result to success).
because of the problem mentioned above I can't do it... any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: are you also doing build.setResult for the case where there result is a success, in your question it is missing?!

Comment: sure. I just changed the SUCCESS to UNSTABLE.

Comment: Maybe you can fire a batch command to force exit code 0 if your condition is met?

Comment: But I need that the main Job will keep running... It still needs to send mails, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this expected behavior with Jenkins.  Other methods of changing the build result (such as the [Fail The Build plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Fail+The+Build+Plugin)) also cannot "improve" the build status, they can only make it worse (success to unstable to failed).

Comment: I added some information in the question, do you have any solution?

Answer (score -1):

Using [Post Build plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PostBuildScript+Plugin) and [Groovy System Script](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin), you can change build result with ***Result.fromString()*** , for example, setting result to "Unstable":

```
build.result = hudson.model.Result.fromString('UNSTABLE')
```

[image]

In the Console you'll see:

> [PostBuildScript] - Execution post build scripts.
>
> [Current build status] check if current [ABORTED] is worse or equals then [ABORTED] and better or equals then [UNSTABLE]
>
> Run condition [Current build status] enabling perform for step [Execute system Groovy script]
>
> Script returned: UNSTABLE